# Multiple Solr filter queries in PHP

Tags: php, solr, facet

I am trying to use facet in solr, i want to make a search on my database and i need to get  articles that belong to specific date and specific publisher.

i used this url on the browser:
localhost:8888/solr//collection1/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&facet=true&fq=publisher_name:"Saudi Press Agency (SPA)"&fq=datecreated:20110725

and it works fine. I am using (search()) function in apache_solr_service class in my php code. and i set the array as below:

```
array('facet'=>'true','fq'=>"datecreated:".$date,'fq'=>"publisher_name:\"".$publisher.'"')
```

I know it wont give me the expected results because of fq index, it will overwrite the value of fq into publisher_name

but how can i set this query with two facet queries

Answer (score 1):

This might help: 
http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/FAQ#How_Can_I_Use_Additional_Parameters_%28like_fq,_facet,_etc%29

This is what the code should look like (please check for syntax errors, my PHP is rusty):
`array('facet'=>'true','fq'=>array('datecreated:'.$date,'publisher_name:"'.$publisher.'"')`

Answer (score 1):

You could also write it like this:

```
array('fq'=>'+datecreated:'.$date.' +publisher_name:"'.$publisher.'"')
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq

Answer (score 0):

use AND operator:

```
array('fq'=> 'datecreated:'.$date.' AND publisher_name:"'.$publisher.'"');
```